# Me dice que el método darDisponibilidad no está definido para el tipo ChivaRumbera

Tags: java

```
private String nombre;

/**
 * Tamanio de la chiva rumbera
 */
// TODO
// Definir el atributo que representa el tamaño de la chiva rumbera según la documentación

private String tamanio;

/**
 * Precio del alquiler por hora
 */
private double precioHora;

/**
 * Disponibilidad de la chiva rumbera
 */
// TODO
// Definir el atributo que representa la disponibilidad de la chiva rumbera según la documentación

private boolean disponible;

/**
 * Número de veces que ha sido alquilado la chiva rumbera
 */
private int vecesAlquilado;

/**
 * Cantidad de dinero recaudado por el alquiler de la chiva rumbera
 */
private double dineroRecaudado;


// -----------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructores
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Constructor de la clase, se encarga de crear un nueva chiva rumbera según los parámetros
 * @param pNombre El nombre de la chiva rumbera - pNombre != null
 * @param pTamanio El tamanio de la chiva rumbera - pTamanio != null
 * @param pPrecio El precio de alquiler de la chiva rumbera por hora - pPrecio > 0
 */
public ChivaRumbera( String pNombre, String pTamanio, double pPrecio )
{
    nombre = pNombre;
    tamanio = pTamanio;
    precioHora = pPrecio;
    disponible = true;

    // TODO
    // Completar el método de construcción de un objeto

}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
// Métodos
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Devuelve el nombre de la chiva rumbera
 * @return Nombre de la chiva rumbera
 */
public String darNombre() 
{
    return nombre;
}


/**
 * Devuelve el tamanio de la chiva rumbera
 * @return Tamanio de la chiva rumbera
 */
public String darTamanio() 
{
return tamanio;
}

public double darPrecioHora() 
{
    return precioHora;
}

public boolean darDisponibiliad()
{
    return disponible;  
}

public int darVecesAlquilado() 
{
    return vecesAlquilado;
}

public double darDineroRecaudado()
{
    return dineroRecaudado;
}

/**
 * Alquila una chiva rumbera el número de horas dado como parámetro <br />
 * <b> post:</b> Se aumenta en 1 el número de veces que ha sido alquilada la chiva rumbera. <br />
 * Se establece en falso la disponibilidad de la chiva rumbera. <br /> 
 * Se aumenta la cantidad de dinero recaudado en el valor del alquiler de la chiva rumbera. <br />
 * Se calcular el valor del alquiler de la chiva rumbera teniendo en cuenta el descuento. <br />
 * @param pHoras Número de horas a alquilar la chiva rumbera - pHoras > 0
 * @return Valor del alquiler de la chiva rumbera.   
 */
public double alquilarChivaRumbera( int pHoras )
{
vecesAlquilado ++;
disponible = false;
double descuento = (precioHora * pHoras)*darDescuento (pHoras);
double valorAlquiler =(precioHora * pHoras)- descuento;
dineroRecaudado += precioHora * pHoras;

return valorAlquiler;

}

/**
 * Devuelve una chiva rumbera que fue previamente alquilada<br />
 * <b> post:</b> Se establece en verdadero la disponibilidad de la chiva rumbera. <br /> 
 */
public void devolverChivaRumbera()
{

disponible = true;

}
/**
 * Reinicia una chiva rumbera estableciéndola como disponible, el número de veces que ha sido alquilada <br />
 * y la cantidad de dinero recaudado en cero. <br />
 */
public void reiniciar()
{

disponible = true;
vecesAlquilado = 0;
dineroRecaudado = 0;

}


/**
 * Devuelve el valor del descuento dependiendo del número de horas del alquiler.
 * <b> post:</b> Dependiendo del número de horas recibido por parámetro, retorna el porcentaje del descuento a aplicar:<br>
 * - Si el número de horas es menor o igual a 2  retorna 0<br />
 * - Si el número de horas está 3 y 6            retorna 0.05 <br />
 * - Si el número de horas está 7 y 12           retorna 0.08 <br />
 * - Si el número de horas está 13 y 24          retorna 0.10 <br />
 * - Si el número de horas es mayor o igual a 25 retorna 0.15 <br />
 * @param pHoras Número de horas a alquilar la chiva rumbera - pHoras > 0
 * @return Porcentaje de descuento a aplicar representado en una fracción de 1.
 */

public double darDescuento( int pHoras )
{
double valorDescuento = 0.0;
if (pHoras <= 2) 
{
    valorDescuento = 0.0;
    return valorDescuento;
} 
else if (pHoras >= 3 && pHoras <= 6)
{
    valorDescuento = 0.05;
    return valorDescuento;
} 
else if (pHoras >= 7 && pHoras <= 12)
{
    valorDescuento= 0.08;
    return valorDescuento;
}
else if (pHoras >= 13 && pHoras <= 24)
{
    valorDescuento = 0.10;
    return valorDescuento;
}
else 
{
    valorDescuento = 0.15;
    return valorDescuento;
}

}
}
```

Comment: Sí? Y qué pasa con todo este código? Dónde está el error?

Comment: Has nombrado mal el método. Lo has llamado `darDisponibiliad()` en  vez de `darDisponibilidad()`

Comment: Tenías razón, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el metodo mal nombredo en la clase.

```
public boolean darDisponibiliad(){
    return disponible;  
}
```

Corrige a esto. Le falta la d:

```
public boolean darDisponibilidad(){
        return disponible;  
}
```